# Component not working in ionic tabs template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just started with Ionic and  Angular 
I have  created an ionic app based on tabs template.
I add a component using

```
ionic g component rabat
```

when I add the component to the routing file it's making my app becoming blank 
(it's not showing anymore in http://localhost:8100/)

this is my app.routing.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RabatComponent } from './rabat/rabat.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'rabat', component: RabatComponent },

  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  { path: 'tab4', loadChildren: './tab4/tab4.module#Tab4PageModule' },
  { path: 'tab5', loadChildren: './tab5/tab5.module#Tab5PageModule' },
  { path: 'tab6', loadChildren: './tab6/tab6.module#Tab6PageModule' },
  { path: 'tab7', loadChildren: './tab7/tab7.module#Tab7PageModule' },
  { path: 'tab8', loadChildren: './tab8/tab8.module#Tab8PageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I'm I doing something wrong? I just started with both technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you auto generated the ionic tabs app, you get a file named "tabs.module.ts". This file has all the tab routing.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

My guess is that you auto generated the blank app, which has an app.routing.ts file that looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},
  { path: 'options', loadChildren: './options/options.module#OptionsPageModule' },
  { path: 'search', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchPageModule' }    
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```